# Swipe with jQuery Mobile 1.2, PhoneGap 2.1 and Android 4.0.4 not working properly

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, swipe

I know there are already a bzillion threads about this, but I cannot get a solution.

Problem: Not every swipe gesture is recognized.

Setup: Android 4.0.4, PhoneGap 2.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.2

On a touchMove (scroll or swipe) I get (almost every time)

```
Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

The problem seems to be that my setup is not able to detect a touchstop properly.

I using the following at the moment for swiping:

```
(".mainList").swipeleft(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("status.html", {
        transition : "slide"
    });
    console.log("swipe left!!!");
});
```

and this for enabling the swipe to be triggered correctly every time:

```
// deactivate normal touch handling for swipe to work
document.ontouchmove = function(event) {    
        event.preventDefault();
};
```

This way swiping works every time but scrolling (of course) does not work anymore. You could apply this function only for the header of a page to make the header "swipable" and the content scrollable but not swipeable correctly. But this cannot be the real solution.

I tried the following tips I gathered from various thread:

- use the ".on" function to bind the swipe event
- bind the swipe event to a class rather than an id
- Try to detect a horizontal scroll by using "ontouchstart" and "ontouchend"
  This does not work as the touchend event is not triggered on every swipe.
- experiment with different values of the swipe constants like $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold

As I thought maybe the setup is not show whether a swipe is a real swipe or a horizontal scroll:

- prevent horizontal scrolling via css overflow
- prevent horizontal scrolling by using a customized cordovarwebview
- use different values fo the viewport meta tag in my html to set the correct page width

All trials except the event.preventDefault(); approach do not change the situation: only every second, third or fourth swipe gesture is recognized correctly.

Anyone with the same problem and maybe a solution? :D
Thx in advance

Comment: Thanks for the tip of `touchmove`. It, at least, partially solved my problem. I bound `vmousemove` on all pages except my first page (which is an index page with a scrollable list) and it performs much better now.

Comment: nice one work fine....

Comment: I'm having the same issue. But I notice that without PhoneGap it works fine when I call the page from the phone's browser. It is while going through PhoneGap that this issue comes up.