# Laggy swipe performance

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a jQuery Mobile application that I'm trying to run on a Galaxy Tab device via Phonegap. Everything works as expected, but I have a swipe used to transition between a set of pages and it is horrendously laggy.

I'm actually using knockoutJS and a custom binding like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: factors -->
<div data-role="page" data-bind="attr: { id: id }, swipe: $data"> 
    <!-- some content here that I don't *think* is the problem -->
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

ko.bindingHandlers["swipe"] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var qe = $(element);
        var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        qe.bind("swipeleft", function () {
            var next = qe.next("div[data-role='page'][data-bind*='swipe']");
            if(next.length) {
                $.mobile.changePage(next, {
                    transition: "slide"
                });
            } else {
                qe.effect("shake");
            }
        });
        qe.bind("swiperight", function () {
            var prev = qe.prev("div[data-role='page']");
            if(prev.length) {
                $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
                    transition: "slide",
                    reverse: true
                });
            } else {
                qe.effect("shake");
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried removing pretty much all the content from the pages and that didn't help. I tried replacing the `slide` transition with `none` and that helped a little, but the performance is still unacceptably slow.

Any tricks or tips to make this work reasonably well?

Comment: A wild guess.  Is your pictures large in size (MB, KB) ?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't have any pictures. I was drawing graphs on each page as the page was made visible, but even removing that it's still laggy.

Comment: And btw.. Android vs Transitions is not good.  With Jquery Mobile you just need to disable transitions, because they dosetn work well on android devices.  This is soemthing that Jquery Mobile team do know about, so its being worked on. I take it that you are using transitions and maybe you should look at that.  I had a lot of experience with transitions and i know that sometimes they can play around.

Comment: Laggy as in they swype over the page slowly?

Comment: @Daniel: I tried changing the transitions to `none`, and it helped some, but it was still noticeably laggy.

Comment: @Daniel: Laggy as in you swipe and nothing happens. You swipe again and still nothing happens, you swipe a few more times and it finally decides to do something. Other times it'll swipe first time. The transitions themselves run okay.

Comment: can you paste your project to pastebin or something, or just as some sort of zip file from ex. a domain?   I kinda want to see this myself on my own phone, if thats not to much trouble :)

Comment: Or may i suggest another swype plugin just for the sport of it: http://wipetouch.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gave me a partial solution at least:

[Swipe with jQuery Mobile 1.2, PhoneGap 2.1 and Android 4.0.4 not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838443/swipe-with-jquery-mobile-1-2-phonegap-2-1-and-android-4-0-4-not-working-properl)

It seems that binding `vmousemouse` and setting it to `preventDefault` makes the swipes work much better, but at the same time it disables scrolling!

Comment: Did you mean `vmousemove`?